# (REOPENED) Reopen "How do I tell if a position I am being offered is a Demotion?"

Tags: support, reopen-request

[How do I tell if a position I am being offered is a Demotion?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/92625/is-going-from-software-engineer-to-test-engineer-a-demotion/92631#92631)

The question title is

> How do I tell if a position I am being offered is a Demotion?

the quesiton has been edited from its original form and no longer asks for career guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Just case reopen vote #5. Nice work on the edits to the question.