# Reopened question rolled back to closed revision. Now what do we do?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, rollback

This question [Is going from Software Engineer to Test Engineer a demotion?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/92625/3192) was put on hold as off-topic. It was then reopened after an [edit](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/revisions/92625/2) and a [meta post](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4539/3192).

The question has since been rolled back to the original version. Now what are we supposed to do about it? The edit which made the question "reopenable" has been rolled back, so should the question remain open?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I rolled it back to the version.

There are a few meta posts on this now (this one, and [this one](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4539/2322)) a blatant rollback seems a bit inappropriate.

I put a comment on the question to direct future users considering rollback to first consider the meta discussions.